# create jar file with dependencies with gradle build Jar description

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, gradle

I tried to create a jar library using following format of gradle build so that it can later imported as jar package by others in there project. But, generated jar have only one manifest file and no java files.

This files are in a package in eclipse.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

  version = 'v2.1'

  task makejar (type: Jar){
      baseName = 'protocols-binarydevice'
      version = 'v2.2'
      from('binarydevice/')
      into('binarydevice/')

  }

  dependencies {
      compile 'xxx.api.messages:ProtocolRole'
      compile 'xxx.api.messages:Event'
      compile 'xxx.api.messages:UhuMessage'
  }
```

Thankx.

Answer (score 0):

See [following example](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/) to create jar with dependencies. Your build script lacks following lines.

```
task makejar (type: Jar) {
    ....
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Error: Cannot resolve external dependency xxx.api.messages:ProtocolRole: because no repositories are defined.

Comment: Added the repositories pointing to local location where they were present. But return with Error : Could not find com.bosch.upa.uhu.api.messages:ProtocolRole:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:(pathtolibraries)/lib/ProtocolRole-.jar
  Required by :protocols:v2.1